# What is the difference between a dividend and share distribution?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, vanguard

For example for one of Vanguard's funds it stated:

> FTSE Developed World ex-U.K. Equity Index Fund - Accumulation
>   (FPC9.GB) has declared a GBP 6.167605000 per share final distribution.
>   Group 2 units will have an equalisation rate of 3.285574000 applied

This does not seem to be the same as a 'dividend' - so what is it? What terms can I search / investigate for to understand it? I didn't seem to have much luck with "share distribution".

Comment: Lots of articles out there.  Google: "Difference between dividend and distributions"

Answer (score 1):

Contacted Vanguard and they stated:

> FTSE Developed World ex-U.K. Equity Index Fund - Accumulation fund,
>   which reinvests all the underlying dividends back into the fund, at a
>   fund level. This means that over time, the value of each unit
>   increases with this increased investment, as these are not paid out to
>   investors accounts directly.

Comment: did this answer your question?